# What is Hurricane Electric's IPv6-enabled DNS server?

Tags: ipv6

Hurricane Electric has IPv6-enabled DNS servers for use with their tunnelbroker. What are the addresses for these servers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are listed in your tunnel configuration page, under "Available DNS resolvers". It's possible that they vary for different tunnel servers, but here are those shown for my Frankfurt tunnel:

- `2001:470:20::2`
- `74.82.42.42`

Comment: They don't differ; they are anycasted.